# Force Windows 8 to Boot Into USB/DVD

Tags: windows-8, boot, password-recovery

My friend's grandfather recently died, and as the local go-to tech guy they came to me with his desktop computer to try to get into it.

It is a Windows 8.1 Acer desktop computer, model AXC-603-UB17. I've been unable to reset his hotmail email password, but this is irrelevant because the computer refuses to connect to the internet.

Besides trying hundreds of different passwords based on his birthdate etc..., I'm trying to boot it into ophcrack or trinity rescue kit... however it won't boot into either, regardless of whether I try USB or CD. Both the CDs and USBs work, as I can boot my laptop using them.

In the boot settings I turned secure boot off, set the boot order to 1) CD/DVD 2) Removable Drive 3) LAN 4) Windows Boot Manager, however on boot it always goes straight to windows. If I press F12 or DEL to select a boot device, the only one that appears is Windows Boot Manager.

The USB ports are working, as the USB keyboard and mouse work in all slots. I'm not sure how to continue from here. Is there a way I can, for example, remove the hard drive and so it will be forced to boot into the DVD/USB?

Comment: Have you tried telling windows to restart?  Windows 8 likes to boot completely then give you options, the fast boot "feature".  Otherwise yea you can unplug the sata cable from the hdd and see if that lets you go.  You can hot plug sata so after you boot from usb/cd you can plug the hdd back in.

Comment: @Foosh Yes, I've been restarting it. I tried uplugging the sata cable and it (obviously) stopped booting to windows, however it still didn't detect the bootable media in the DVD or the USB...

Comment: sounds like they might be disabled in bios...  what are the settings for legacy mode (usb) if any as well as the sata/ide controller settings?  does the POST screen tell you it's detected a usb drive and cd/dvd drive?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I took the HDD out and plugged it into my other computer, which allowed me to boot into it.